# Why subclasses of primitive types take more memory in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-internals

I'm trying to subclass primitive types in Python like this (simplified version):

```py
class MyInt(int):
    pass
```

I thought that an object of this class would take the same amount of memory as the primitive one. But, apparently, that's not true:

```py
import sys
sys.getsizeof(10)          # 24
sys.getsizeof(MyInt(10))   # 72
```

Using `__slots__`, I was able to save some memory, but the subclass still takes more space:

```py
class MyInt(int):
    __slots__ = ()


sys.getsizeof(10)          # 24
sys.getsizeof(MyInt(10))   # 56
```

If I subclass my own classes, on the other hand, the memory usage is the same:

```py
class Father(object):
    pass


class Son(Father):
    pass

sys.getsizeof(Father())  # 64
sys.getsizeof(Son())     # 64
```

1. Why does the subtype object use more memory than the primitive type object, if there are no extra fields?
2. Is there a way to prevent (or minimize) this?

I'm using Python 2.7.12.

Comment: One way to reduce memory consumption in general is the "Flyweight Pattern" a.k.a. "interning" of values. In Python, you can overload `__new__` and look up the instance in a dictionary instead of creating a new one.

Comment: In python3, there will not be a difference in size if you force slots to be empty.

Comment: An instance of a user-defined class still has things like a list of its base classes, which occupies memory. Why are you defining `MyInt` in the first place?

Comment: as a general rule subclassing built-in types is seldom a good idea - composition / delegation is usually a better solution.

Comment: @chepner I want to create value objects (in DDD sense) to represent concepts like, for instance, a product ID, product price, and so on. A product ID is not an int, it's a subset of an int, because only integers greater than zero are valid IDs. These types would encapsulate these rules.

Comment: That's something that Python really doesn't do well, at least without an unavoidable runtime cost.

Comment: @BlownhitherMa you're right, thanks! I've tested and, in Python 3, subclasses with empty `__slots__` of `int`, `float`, `Decimal`, `date` and `datetime` use the same space as the primitive ones. The only exception seems to be the subtypes of `str` which use 32 bytes more.

Answer (score 1):

Subclassing built-in classes was only possible in Python when "new style classes" were created in Python 2.2. So, without looking at the code, or reading carefully the presentation notes at this [Guido's article](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/), it is possible to infer that some boilerplate internal fields are needed in Python2 to allow built-in classes (which had their code base written prior to the unification) to work and behave well as "user defined classes" when subclassed. (That is "object" behavior that is not built-in the code base for "old-style" "int" objects).

Whatever takes place is somewhere inside [Python's 2.7 `Objects/typeobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/typeobject.c) - so you may take a look there (or wait until someone who can more easily analyse that come up with another answer)

That, as @blownhither_ma mentions in the comments above, seems not to be the case in Python3 anymore - I'd say the class unification have been consolidated since 2009:

```
In [158]: from sys import getsizeof as sizeof

In [159]: sizeof(int())
Out[159]: 24

In [160]: class MInt(int):
     ...:     __slots__ = ()
     ...:     

In [161]: sizeof(MInt())
Out[161]: 24
```

So, while there are things yet to be answered on your question, they matter only for Python 2, which no one should be using in new code by now.